# How can I restrict access to members in an assembly from Roslyn script engine?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, roslyn, scriptengine

I am experimenting with the Roslyn script engine.  Using the following code, I set up my script engine.

```
var csharpEngine = new ScriptEngine();

csharpEngine.AddReference("System");

csharpEngine.AddReference(this.GetType().Assembly.Location);            

scriptSession = csharpEngine.CreateSession();
```

Then I execute a script with the following line:

```
scriptSession.Execute(script);
```

The script contains a very simple reference to a static function on a class in my assembly.

```
private string script = 
@"using System;
using RoslynWindow;

Hello.SayHello();";
```

In the output window the function merely prints to the console.  So I have shown I can call into a public static member of my assembly without passing a "HostObjectModel" to the script engine.  I want to *prevent* this from happening.  I'd like to be able to register only specific members (functions, variables or properties) to be accessed by the script engine, and no others.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Potentially stupid question: Isn't the `scriptengine` tag specific to Java?

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the AST with Roslyn to check if the script tries to call anything you don't allow.